# Не срабатывает функция получения строки getline

Tags: строки, c++

В коде идет 8 вызовов функции getline подряд, перемежающиеся выводом через cout. При этом первый из вызовов getline просто пропускается в время работы, а все остальные работают. синтаксических ошибок быть не может. Компилятор также никаких ошибок не выдает.

```
Address::Address(void)
{

string Organisation, Country, Region, Town, Street, House, Corpus, Flat;

string adr[8];

    cout << endl << "Введите название организации: ";
    getline(cin, Organisation);
    cout << endl << "Введите страну: ";
    getline(cin, Country);
```

Comment: Кто нибудь из ввода до первого getline оставил в буфере конец строки (newline). Типичная ошибка.

Comment: Как посоветуете исправить ошибку?

Comment: **Внимательно** прочесть свой код.

Comment: в других языках та же проблема. Поэтому переход не поможет.

К тому же, в с++ коде выше проблемы нет. Просто нужно понимать, что читать нужно аккуратно, с++ за вас никогда не угадает, что нужно прочитать.

Comment: @KoVadim: Можете привести пример такой проблемы с C/`scanf`?

Comment: @VladD, Ваш ответ правильный, но не могу разобраться, как это отметить на сайте.

Comment: @Андрей Темников: преобразовал в ответ.

Comment: @VladD - Ваш пример плохой - у Вас только один scanf. Плюс ко всему, если бы TC вводил числа, а не строки, проблемы то не было бы. Очень упрощенный вариант на с


    int main(void) {
      int c;
      size_t dd=10;
      char * t=(char*)malloc(dd+1);
      scanf("%d", &c);
      getline (&t, &dd, stdin);
      printf("%s\n", t);
      free(t);
      return 0;
    }

ожидаем, что введем число, потом строку. По факту, ее не дает ввести. Конечно, можно написать `scanf("%d\n", &c)`. Это известная проблема - не мешать getline и другие способы ввода.

Comment: @KoVadim: И правда. По крайней мере, в C# я с подобной проблемой никогда не сталкивался — у класса `Console` есть лишь [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.console.readline). Можно, конечно, сконструировать искусственный пример с `Read`, читающий по одному символу, но им никто не пользуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Андрей Темников](/users/19464/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2): локально — попробуйте

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Глобально — мигрируйте на более человечные языки программирования.